Time travelling soccer player
I've forgot the title of a movie, it's not an old movie, pretty much sure, and its about a teenager boy who plays soccer and that time travels back in time.. and he ends up falling in love with a girl and somehow he manage to get back with the girl.

Language\country? It's always advised to add any detail you can possibly think of (posted a possible match below anyway).

Could be the Dutch film Crusade in Jeans from 2006. From Wiki:

Dolf is a 15-year-old boy from Rotterdam who plays for the junior national football team. At the beginning of the film, Dolf and his team are playing an important championship game against the Belgian team in the German city of Speyer, which they lose because of Dolf.
Dolf's mother works in a research centre in Rotterdam where a time machine has been developed.

Dolf uses the machine in order to replay the match, but he accidentally goes back to 1212 and then joins the Children's Crusade to Jerusalem. He meets a girl named Jenne and eventually brings her with him to the present. Here's the trailer:



